# Userdnsdomain vs userdomain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

What's the difference between **userdnsdomain** and **userdomain**? Why the userdnsdomain  can be called different than userdomain?
Example:

**userdnsdomain:** SU.SUPERUSER.LOCAL

**userdomain:** SUPERSU

Comment: It is not case :) 
In my company this it looks so :) When I wrote  command set in cmd, 
I saw such settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to obtain these values in my development environment I got it as:

```
userdnsdomain - dev.local
userdomain - dev
```

The details of these terms are as below:

`userdnsdomain` - DNS name or [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (Fully Qualified Domain Name) of a domain (e.g. `dev.local` in my lab)

`userdomain` - It is [netbios domain name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc961556(v=technet.10)) (e.g. `dev` in my lab)

You can also check this - [Is the NetBIOS name of the domain different from the domain name?](http://smallcitydesign.com/netbios-name/)

Also read this thread - [Diferent UserDomain from UserDNSDomain](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a1cdafe-c164-4653-9345-0a543fc11d10/diferent-userdomain-from-userdnsdomain?forum=winserveripamdhcpdns)

**P.S.** Just for additional information. In powershell there are environment variables to obtain these values for a computer:

```
$env:USERDNSDOMAIN
$env:USERDOMAIN
```

Comment: At the moment all is clarity for me. Thanks!

Comment: The page **Is the NetBIOS name of the domain different from the domain name?** is no longer available, but can be found on the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20201112020355/https://smallcitydesign.com/netbios-name/